# R: Error using summary() on lm() result -- only when using RStudio

Tags: r

Recently RStudio began misbehaving.  lm() on a model works, but using summary() on the lm() throws the error:

Error in summary.lm(fit) : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
In addition: Warning message:
In cbind(est,se,tval,2*pt(abs(tval),rdf,lower.tail=FALSE)) : 
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg1)

This happens even when I run a simple linear model in RStudio:

```
y <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
x <- c(1,3,2,5,4)
fit <- lm(y ~ x)
summary(fit)
```

However, running this simple model in RGUI does not throw the exception.

This is puzzling to me because yesterday RStudio was not throwing exceptions when I used summary() on an lm().  But now the code that I used yesterday is no longer working.  The code that ran the prior linear models did not change. The only differences is that the data I loaded into memory today was slightly larger than before.  Before it was about 45 gigabytes (huge file -- methylation data).  Now it has a few megabytes of extra variables.  And maybe that breaks things somehow.

I am suspicious that the problem has something to do with memory management, strangely enough, but I have no idea.

Does anyone have any idea where the problem might come from?

EDIT:

I restarted the computer, reopened RStudio, and got the same error.  Then I closed RStudio and reopened it again and now I can't reproduce the error.  I have no idea what is going on.  I'd still like some insights into what is going on so I don't wasted another several hours being confused about why things that should work don't and then suddenly start working again.

Comment: `sessionInfo()` will be required for such a problem

Comment: This is not RStudio related, but rather the work of automation. See http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/loading-workspace-getting-annoying-td3004781.html

Answer (score 1):

You might be loading in some old data or workspace variables after you closed your first RStudio session. To fix that problem, you probably want to modify your global options to never restore the `.RData` file on startup and to never save on in the first place, as suggested in Hadley Wickham's R for Data Science book [section on RStudio](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/intro.html).

[Image showing how to change defaults in RStudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdoSm.png)

Another issue might be from some other package in your workspace, as  MichaelChirico has alluded to.

I hope that helps.